# Support for background images in CkEditor5

Tags: image, background, ckeditor5

I'm struggling to find a way to add a background image to a page (or a table in a page) being created in CkEditor5.

I didn't find native support for it, nor any custom plugins. Which is strange, I would imagine there would be some custom ones.

I've also tried creating my own plugin. The idea is that upon selecting an image I would set "background" attribute of a  element to that image's URL. But I got stuck at locating that  element. So I'm not even sure this would be the right approach.

Any help is appreciated.